# Bitbucket flags pipeline as invalid, but passes online validation?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

We use Bitbucket Cloud

I have the following `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file. I removed the actual `script` steps to make it more concise.

```
image: node:9.8.0

definitions:
  caches:
    node-custom-staging: my_project/node_modules
  steps:
    - step: &npm_install
        name: NPM install
        caches:
          - node
          - node-custom-staging
        script:
          - ...
    - step: &build_and_test
        name: Build and Test
        script:
          - parallel:
              - step:
                  caches:
                    - node
                    - node-custom-staging
                  name: Check coding and scss standards
                  script:
                    - ...
              - step:
                  caches:
                    - node
                    - node-custom-staging
                  size: 2x
                  name: Check Build
                  script:
                    - ...
              - step:
                  caches:
                    - node
                    - node-custom-staging
                  size: 2x
                  name: Execute unit test cases
                  script:
                    - ...
    - step: &manage_version
        name: Manage Version
        size: 2x
        script:
          - ...

pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '{feature/*,hotfix/*,bugfix/*,patch/*,breaking/*,release/*}':
      - step: *manage_version
      - step: *npm_install
      - step: *build_and_test
  branches:
    master:
      - step: *npm_install
      - step: *build_and_test
```

Bitbucket gives me this error

```
There is an error in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml at [pipelines > pull-requests > {feature/*,hotfix/*,bugfix/*,patch/*,breaking/*,release/*} > 2 > step > script > 0]. To be precise: Missing or empty command string. Each item in this list should either be a single command string or a map defining a pipe invocation.
```

But yet if I cut/paste in [Validator for bitbucket-pipelines.yml](https://bitbucket-pipelines.prod.public.atl-paas.net/validator), it passes validation. What am I missing? TIA

Comment: The validator is just for very basic config checking. Remove the irrelevant step definitions and include the actual script lines for the erroring definition so we can determine what there could be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parallel build and test pipeline is all wrong. The `parallel` definition must be at the same level as any other `step`, not inside a step's script!

```
image: node:9.8.0

definitions:
  caches:
    node-custom-staging: my_project/node_modules
  steps:
    - &npm_install_step
        name: NPM install
        caches:
          - node
          - node-custom-staging
        script:
          - ...
    - &build_and_test_workflow
        parallel:
          - step:
              caches:
                - node
                - node-custom-staging
              name: Check coding and scss standards
              script:
                - ...
          - step:
              caches:
                - node
                - node-custom-staging
              size: 2x
              name: Check Build
              script:
                - ...
          - step:
              caches:
                - node
                - node-custom-staging
              size: 2x
              name: Execute unit test cases
              script:
                - ...
    - &manage_version_step
        name: Manage Version
        size: 2x
        script:
          - ...

pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '{feature/*,hotfix/*,bugfix/*,patch/*,breaking/*,release/*}':
      - step: *manage_version_step
      - step: *npm_install_step
      - *build_and_test_workflow
  branches:
    master:
      - step: *npm_install_step
      - *build_and_test_workflow
```

I guess your code is syntactically valid YAML but the script elements aren't tested until an agent attempts to run them.